# Как загрузить много изображений в элемент RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, listview, activity

У меня есть RecyclerView с данными, там TextView, ImageView и т.п. Я у меня есть List со строками, строки это url картинок. Хотелось бы как-то отобразить их, как например в Вконтакте, скриншот ниже. Картинок от 0 до 10 может быть в листе. Как лучше организовать это дело?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Я перепутал домены :) По сути вопрос понятен же?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я отредактировал.

Comment: Вопрос понятен и есть даже [похожий](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434376/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%92%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4), но ответ ни мне неизвестен, ни на другом вопросе его нема. И либ я никаких не нашёл. Видать придётся вам как-то самому сие реализовывать измеряя картинки их вручную располагая в разметке.

Answer (score 1):

Существует довольно большое количество библиотек для асинхронной загрузки изображений с кэшированием как на диске так и в памяти. Наиболее известные: [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [ion](https://github.com/koush/ion), [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco), [Volley](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/volley/index.html).

Вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide) на сравнение нескольких библиотек (англоязычный stackoverflow).

Общий принцип работы: конфигурируем параметры (кэширование на диске, в памяти и т.п.) и отдаем библиотеке ImageView по принципу запустил и забыл. Библиотека сама в отдельном потоке скачивает изображение (или берет его из кэша), уменьшает до требуемого размера и сеттит его в ImageView. Для быстрого старта достаточно добавить всего несколько строк в адаптер списка. Для нестандартных изображений вроде svg часть библиотек позволяет добавить свой декодер.

Примеры использования с кодом есть на страничках практически всех библиотек.
Вот пример с picasso:

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
    .placeholder(R.drawable.image)
    .resize(50, 50)
    .into(imageView)
```

По моему субъективному (и не факт что правильному) мнению UIL в данном списке наиболее гибок в части тонкой настройки загрузки изображений, но при этом picasso более прост в настройке и внедрении. Библиотеку ion я сам не пробовал, но многие отзываются о ней очень хорошо.

**Добавлено**: Судя по уточнениям к вопросу проблема состоит не сколько в загрузке изображений по ссылкам, сколько в их динамической компоновке на экране. Единственная как мне кажется подходящая для такой цели библиотека это [QuiltViewLibrary](https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary).

Comment: Хм. Судя по всему я не очень понял вопрос. Цель какая ? Просто загрузить картинки в разметку ? Или разметку динамически делать ?

Comment: Динамической сделать